# How to upload pdf file with csv

Tags: csv, upload, pdf-uploads

How can we upload a pdf file to Magento from an external server with CSV file?

For example, I have this on the CSV file `pdf_upload=https://www.externalserver.com/datasheets/97/D38999-24JJ24HB.pdf`

when I upload the CSV to Magento the PDF should be downloaded to my server

Thanks

Comment: Are you trying to upload a CSV file that contains the URL to a pdf files

Comment: Yes correct. The pdf on the csv file is with url

Comment: You need to provide a lot more information. Like where are you uploading the CSV to (i.e products)? It is possible but will require a lot of custom codes

Comment: Yes I am uploading the CSV to products. So when I want to add a new products through CSV one of the fields is the PDF link that is from external website so it should be downloaded to my website like we do for the images. (the images are downloading from external website url to my website)

Comment: Have you thought about creating a custom product attribute to store the pdf URL?

Comment: Yes I have created a custom attribute but the problem is that I dont want it to be from the other server. I want the path to be with my domain.

Comment: The attribute will be a text field that contains the domain/path to the pdf files